# Spring Boot 2.0, read max request size, max file size configuration values at runtime

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

With a default implementation of Spring Boot 2.0, is there a way to inject a reference to the container configuration so that I can read the value of the max request size(post), and max file size property at runtime?

I was thinking something like this would work in a `@Configuration` class, but it doesn't resolve to a value.

```
@Value("${server.tomcat.max-http-post-size}")
public String maxPostSize;
```

Comment: Do you mean the multipart's max request size and max file size? you can inject the  `MultipartProperties` into your spring bean and get the configured properties values.

Comment: I believe there is a max request size property that controls the max size for a 'post' payload, as well as a property for the multipart max file size. I'll look at the MultiPartProperties and go from there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By injecting [ServerProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.0.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.java) I was able to get access to this information. However, if you are using the 'default' values, then they just come through as '0'. Setting a non-default value is reflected in this object, so this is the correct way to get access to the information.

[image]